# Binding parameters dynamically with mysqli bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so I've been looking up a solution to bind parameters dynamically with php and here is a function that I made.

> > ```
> > public function getEntity($tableName, $fieldList, $keyValueArray = NULL)
> > {
> >     // First construct the sql to be used to get the entity
> >     if(is_array($fieldList))
> >     {
> >         $sql = "SELECT ";
> >         foreach($fieldList as $field)
> >         {
> >             $sql .= $field." , ";
> >         }
> >         $sql = rtrim($sql, ' , ');
> >     }
> >     else
> >     {
> >         $sql = "SELECT ".$fieldList;
> >     }
> >     $sql .= " FROM ".$tableName;
> >     if($keyValueArray != NULL)
> >     {
> >         $sql .= " WHERE ";
> >         foreach($keyValueArray as $key => $value)
> >         {
> >             $sql .= $key." = ? AND ";
> >         }
> >         $sql = rtrim($sql, ' AND ');
> >     }
> >     //Then grab the connection
> >     $connection = $this->getConnection();
> >     //Prepare the statement
> >     $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
> >     if($stmt === false) 
> >     {
> >         trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $connection->errno . ' ' . $connection->error, E_USER_ERROR);
> >     }
> >     // Bind the paramaters
> >     if($keyValueArray != NULL AND count($keyValueArray) < 2)
> >     {
> >         $stmt->bind_param("s", $keyValueArray[key($keyValueArray)]);
> >     }
> >     elseif($keyValueArray != NULL)
> >     {
> >         $valueArray = array();
> >         $string = NULL;
> >         for($i = 0; $i < count($keyValueArray); $i++)
> >         {
> >           $string .= "s"; // for temp solution       
> >         }
> >         $valueArray[] = &$string;
> >         foreach($keyValueArray as $key => $value)
> >         {
> >             $valueArray[] = &$keyValueArray[$key];
> >         }
> >         call_user_func(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $valueArray);
> >     }
> >     //Execute the statement
> >     $stmt->execute();
> >     //Grab the results and stuff into multidimensional array
> >     $data = $stmt->result_metadata();
> >     $fields = array();
> >     $currentrow = array();
> >     $results = array();
> >         //Store references to keys in $currentrow
> >     while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) 
> >     {
> >       $fields[] = &$currentrow[$field->name];
> >     }
> >         // Bind statement to $currentrow using the array of references
> >     call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $fields);
> >         // Iteratively refresh $currentrow array using "fetch", store values from each row in $results array
> >     $i = 0;
> >     while ($stmt->fetch()) 
> >     {
> >         $results[$i] = array();
> >         foreach($currentrow as $key => $val) 
> >         {
> >         $results[$i][$key] = $val;
> >         }
> >     $i++;
> >     }
> >     $connection->close();
> >     return $results;      
> > }
> > ```

I then run this function something like this:

> > ```
> > $keyValueArray['firstName'] = 'John';
> > $keyValueArray['lastName'] = 'Doe';
> > $fieldListArray[] = 'firstName';
> > $fieldListArray[] = 'lastName';
> > print_r($db->getEntity('ACCOUNT', $fieldListArray, $keyValueArray));
> > ```

However, when I run the function. I get an error that says

> > ```
> > Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()
> > ```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, using PDO is much easier for this type of task because you can pass an array of values to `execute()`. No binding required!

Comment: -1. Why bother with prepared statements if you have ALL your query composed from outside variables?

Comment: Does it hurt to your prepared statements in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `call_user_func_array`, not `call_user_func`, when calling `bind_param`.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought I tried that and it didn't work. It works now though.